# MEAN stack - trying to POST gives 404

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

**Background:**

I'm writing my first MEAN application.  I'm trying to create an API that allows basic CRUD ops on a collection called "chassis".

**Problem**

So far, i can GET all records using find().  I can also findById, and update existing records, no problems. 
However, when I try to POST, I get the following error:

```
dev@devbox:~/nimble_express/nimbleApp$ curl -X POST localhost:3000/chassis/ -d name=widget123 -d location=Canada -d ffd=test123 -d hw_model=hp -d asset_tag=12344
<h1>document must have an _id before saving</h1>
<h2></h2>
<pre>Error: document must have an _id before saving
    at null._onTimeout (/home/dev/nimble_express/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:112:18)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)</pre>
dev@devbox:~/nimble_express/nimbleApp$
```

**Code**

I have the following logic in a routes/chassis.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

//var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Chassis = require('../models/Chassis.js');

/* GET chassis listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Chassis.find( function(err, documents) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(documents);
  });
});

/* GET /chassis/id */
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  Chassis.findById(req.params.id, function (err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(post);
  });
});


/* POST /chassis */
router.post('/',function(req, res, next) {
        console.log(req);
  Chassis.create(req.body, function(err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(post);
  });
});

/* UPDATE /chassis/id */
router.put('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  Chassis.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, function(err, post) {
  if (err) return next(err);
  res.json(post);
  });
});

module.exports = router;
~
```

I've tried googling for this error but haven't found anything too useful yet.
Any pointers would be helpful and appreciated!

Comment: It seems to a problem with your a mongoose schema. https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2965

Comment: @SwarajGiri, you're right.  I had "_id: String" as a part of my schema.  I just removed it.  And now the POST is working.  It looks like if you're not going to use your own ids, then you should have anything in the schema referencing that field.